# Should I avoid decimal type in C# when manipulating data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, double, decimal

In current project we IMHO use too much decimal types. We use i.e. for property like Mass which is calculated (multiplications, additions, etc) in BackEnd (C#) and FrontEnd (JavaScript).
The number type in JavaScript is always **64-bit Floating Point** (like double in C#). When converting double to decimal and back there are situations when conversion fails.

Question:
Should the data being manipulated in JavaScript be always **double**?

I created a test which shown when this conversion will fail in C#.

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    double value = 0.000001d;
    value *= 10;
    // Console.WriteLine(value); // 9.9999999999999991E-06
    ConvertToDecimalAndBack(value);
}

private static void ConvertToDecimalAndBack(double doubleValue)
{
    decimal decimalValue = (decimal)doubleValue;

    double doubleResult = (double)decimalValue;

    Assert.Equal(doubleValue, doubleResult);
}
```

Comment: `Should the data being manipulated in JavaScript be always double?` Well, it's not like you have a choice. Any numeric value is represented as the same thing under the hood as you pointed out, so all `int`s are in fact also `double`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question "Should the data being manipulated in JavaScript be always double?" to be one about development policy. As you and comments indicate, max precision in Javascript is `double`. Also, as you point out, the C# decimal type has greater precision than `double`, so conversion issues can occur.

Generally numbers be consistent between processing platforms, especially if numbers are involved in financial transactions or specifically displayed in the UI for some reason.

Here are two options, dependent on specific requirements.

IF you have requirement that JS operates on the original decimal values, you should institute a policy of using `System.Decimal.ToDouble(System.Decimal)` on C# side.

If preserving the decimal value is of utmost importance (ie. it is money)
keep numeric calcs involving decimal values **in one place**, on the server.

Comment: preserving decimal value is not a big concern. IMHO that type is wrong there, we don't need decimal for value of Mass. I am looking for arguments to change it to double. What do you think?

Comment: @KrzysztofMorcinek I think you are right. Match data type to the data model.  1) Semantically double reflects the empirical nature of mass vs 'exact' amounts for financial calculations. 2) Double at 4 bytes requires half the storage of decimal